# NAnt + svn diff - ignore merge commits

Tags: svn, merge, diff, nant

Our (very legacy) codebase has an ActiveX Client UI which requires building and committing the binaries to SVN.

We use a trunk, feature branch and tagged releases repository pattern.

I wrote a NAnt script to compile the release packages by determining the commit revisions of branch and tag creation and using `svn diff` to list the changes to the UI binaries between the two - these are then exported from the repository to generate the release package:

```xml
<exec program="svn.exe" 
      commandline="diff svn://hostname/Project/branches/1.2/Client -r 1234:5678 --summarize --xml" 
      output="c:\Temp\ClientComponents.xml" />

<xmllist file="c:\Temp\ClientComponents.xml" 
         property="ClientComponents" 
         delim="," 
         xpath="/diff/paths/path[@kind = 'file' and @item != 'deleted']" />

<foreach item="String" in="${ClientComponents}" delim="," property="source">

    <!-- svn export -->

</foreach>
```

The output from `svn diff` looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<diff>
<paths>
<path
   item="modified"
   props="none"
   kind="file">svn://hostname/project/branches/1.2/Client/Component1.cab</path>
</paths>
</diff>
```

This has worked fine up until now - as we now have 2 concurrent feature branches.

The first feature branch (e.g. 1.1) has made a change to the Client UI which has correctly been packaged in a 1.1.1 version.

This change has been merged forward into the second branch (e.g. 1.2) and when I now try to package 1.2.1 it includes the Client UI changes that were merged from 1.1

Is there any way to exclude merged changes on the `svn diff` command?

Answer (score 0):

Use the creation date of the 1.2 branch as the first argument to the diff command:

```
svn diff -r {2013-07-09}:HEAD foo
```

**References**

- [Revision Specifiers](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html#svn.tour.revs.keywords)
- [SVN Glossary](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-glossary.html)
- [RFC 3339 - Date and Time on the Internet: Timestamps](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt)